# Stuck in optimizing this question from past few days

Tags: java

linke to the question:
https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/5-paint-ceiling-want-build-house-building-company-hired-build-houses-sides-specific-set-s--q43901799

was asked in an online test by company, couldn't solve it due to time limit , been stuck in my mind for last few days plzz help.

//test case values were very large as even the count variable needed to be of long type so that's why i took variable long.
//timelimit is 4ms.

my solution:

````
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int s=sc.nextInt();
        int k=sc.nextInt();
        int b=sc.nextInt();
        int m=sc.nextInt();
        long a=sc.nextLong();
        long res[]=new long[n];
        res[0]=s;
        long prev=s;
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
            res[i]=((k*prev+b)%m)+1+prev;
            prev=res[i];
        }
        long c=0;
        int f=0;
        int max=res.length;
        for(int i=0;i<max;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i;j<max;j++)
            {
                long prod=res[i]*res[j];
                if(prod<=a)
                {
                    
                    c++;
                    if(i!=j)
                    c++;
                }
                else{
                    if(i==j)
                    {
                    f=1;
                    break;
                    }
                    max=j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(f==1)
            break;
        }
        System.out.print(c);
        return ;
    }
}```
````

Comment: I do not see a question here, maybe ask this over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for better feedback ;) ?

Comment: For the downvoters in the audience: The question is clearly: Here is my algorithm. It produces the correct answer but it is too slow. I don't need my code reviewed, I need somebody to tell me if it can be done faster, and if so, how.

Comment: @lugiorgi OP is not asking for code review. OP is asking for a faster algorithm.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas these kinds of problems never require proper code style, as they are write-only exercises. They test your knowledge of algorithms. It's exactly _BECAUSE_ code style only gets in the way of 'winning' these kinds of problems that asking potential hires to do some coding exercises like this is actually a waste of time and doesn't tell you much. Unless the job they are interviewing for involves a ton of algorithmic work that is performance sensitive. If the google search engine team wants this, I'll give em a pass. If a front-end team does, they're dumb.

Comment: i am really sorry,it's my first post on stackoverflow,so i didn't know about the format, and the naming of variable was like this in the question, as you can see in the question(link provided) i didn't change it, these variable names were used in the question as they have no meaning for eg n,k,b,m please read the question.Will do better next time.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I understood the question as "what could I have done better", sounds like codereview to me. I did not comment that for dismissing them, but to point them to a forum where (in my experience) this kind of question is handled better.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Thanks man for understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you handed in this exact code and the next thing you heard is 'thanks but no thanks', consider that the style is pretty bad (extremely short variable names, the array brackets after the name which is a faux pas in *every* style guide out there, mixing tabs and spaces, yadayada.

But as a rule, that's a little weird: These kinds of coding exercises are all highly academic and usually require you to do otherwise stylistically weird things for time expediency. The whole point is pretty much to create 'write only' code: It does not need to be maintained and the problem description never changes. I would say any company that rates code written for such exercises on style is being very very silly, but it's been known to happen - and one of the comments on your question is, for example, making the same error and thinking that style is somehow important for these exercises.

### Why your algorithm is too slow

The problem is, your algorithm is O(N<sup>2</sup>). But it can be done in O(N log N) - and your optimization simply does not count. It's a clever optimization but it doesn't actually reduce the complexity at all.

Here's a tip for these kinds of problems: Think 'meta'. You could have known that your optimization strategy is useless for the specific problem at hand (specifically, your optimization of turning `max` down once you hit a combo that exceeds `a`):

The problem description would let me define a dataset such that you have, say, n = 6*10<sup>7</sup> (so, 6 million sides), and `a` so large that **every combination of siding** will succeed.

In that case, your algorithm's optimizations simply do not ever kick in, and thus you'd run 6million*6million operations, that's well over 10 billion, and that's more or less the magic number where operations start taking noticable time.

These problems tend to almost always give you that worst case scenario. So, they WILL feed this 'every combination of the many many sidings all fit within `a`' scenario to your algorithm, and thus it will fail due to timeout.

In other words, any optimization you care to add that does nothing to the worst case scenario you can think of **is useless** - these problems are designed and written so that the right optimization works for **every relevant case**. Thus, you could have known that `max=j` trick you cleverly thought of, isn't actually the key answer.

### Okay, so what is the right answer then?

The inner loop is not neccessary.

Let's say your input set of sidings is [2,3,4,5,20,100,101].

Then loop through each siding.

For a given siding: First calculate how large the other siding could possibly be. That's simply `a/2`, `a/3`, etcetera. Next, use binary search to find the highest index whose number is less than or equal to that number (binary search is O(logn)). Then figure out if this siding's number is in that data set (is 2 in there?). If no, add (index*2) to the answer. if yes, subtract 1 from that (because 2/2 is only one config, whereas 2/4 represents 2 configs: 2/4 and 4/2).

And that's it. It's doing an O(1)+O(nlogn) operation n times, for a total complexity of O(nlogn).

O(nlogn) can trivially handle 'n=millions'.

Comment: I will try it out as you suggested ,i could not clear the internship test due to this question and was constantly thinking what could have i done now i know, will try to implement it and keep improving my skills. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please explain with an example

Comment: So i was trying to implement the solution plz correct me where i am wrong: for eg: arr=2,4,6 n=3 a=15 First of all looping through each element of array, for eg for 1st element 2 , now i have to calculate how large other siding could be which is 7 in this case (let a=15). Now i have to find highest index which is less than or equal to 7 in array, which gives us index 2. Now i need to see if 2(the array element) is in dataset??
here i am confused as we already know it is in array, so does it means, everytime we need to do count=2*index -1 ? please clear this doubt.

Comment: So you got index 2, which means every element in the array with index 2 or less is a winner, i.e. just `idx+1`, so, 3 matching sidings. The one issue you're stuck with, is that a 2-by-4 house counts as 1 'point' but so does a 4-by-2 house, so de 4/2 combi counts, effectively, as 2 wins. But a 2-by-2 house counts as only 1 in, that's all that this last thing was about.